# Do we need to enable offline persistence for React Native apps when using Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I saw Todd's video on enabling offline persistence on YouTube, in that he said it is not needed for Android and iOS apps but is required for Web.

But React Native is neither, so do we need to enable it or is it automatic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native involved writing JavaScript for client apps, which means you're using the Firebase JavaScript APIs, which means you're subject to the implementation details of the Firebase web SDKs.  So, if you're using the Firebase web SDKs, you need to explicitly enable offline persistence.